# schema "name" does not exist, but it's a table name

Tags: sql, postgresql, syntax-error

I got `ERROR:  schema "m" does not exist`

my query goes like that:

```
select m.*, e.visit,
    (case when m.order ilike '%stop%' or m.order ilike '%discontinue%' then 'no'
     when mm.number < m.number and mm.name ilike m.name '%maya%' then 'yes'   
     when m.order ilike '%continued%' then 'yes'
     when m.order is null and (quantity is not null or for_how_long is not null) then null
     else '?'
     end) as if_renewed
from medical m
left join table2 e
    on e.id = m.id
inner join medical mm
    on mm.id = m.id
where name ilike '%maya%'
    and visit not ilike '%I%'
```

does anybody know what's wrong here?
thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I got what I did wrong -

```
mm.name ilike m.name '%maya%' then 'yes'
```

I should've deleted `'%maya%'` and write within the query `where m.name ilike '%maya%'` and in the case clause to write `mm.name ilike m.name  then 'yes'`